# Python - splitting sentences dataframe into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sentences in csv that I'd like to split it by the delimiter of spaces.

[image]

I've tried using this :-

```
df2 = df["Text"].str.split()
```

but it doesnt gave out the ideal result. It shows up like this instead.

[image]

I am aware how to do it via power query in excel but I would like to learn how to do similar move using Python.

[image]

Here's the ideal result that I'd like to achieve

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df2 = df["Text"].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in doing this is that the max length of your sentences is going to be fixed. Having said that, you could try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

final_df = original_df['Sentence'].str.split(',', expand=True)

final_df = final_df.add_prefix('Text.')
```

Note that empty columns will be filled with None. If you want these columns to look like empty entries, you could add the following code, which will replace all None's by an empty string:

```
final_df = final_df.replace([None], [''])
```

Hope this will be useful.